# Generation has Thrown an Exception (no explanation aftarwards): on rig

Tags: rigging, rigify

I'm new to blender and have been trying to create a rig for a ported game model using rigify, but when I'm generating the rig I get the error "Generation has Thrown an Exception:" with no explanation behind it. Right now I'm just trying to test to see if the rig will generate but I've been unable to solve this problem, any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have inverted normals and overlapping vertices. You need to select your object, swith to *Edit* mode, select all and:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> in order to recalculate the normals
- Press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*

You'll need to give some corrections in *Weight Pain*t mode though.